# How do I create and register a mixin to ignore properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some Jackson annotated files used for serialization, but I need to change part of its behaviour without changing those files.

Specifically I want to mixin

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

So that it will not throw an `UnrecognizedPropertyException` when some internal properties get added.

How would I create the mixin and register it onto my `ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mix-in class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IgnoreUnknownPropertiesMixin {
}
```

Add the mixin to the associated class

```
Foo user = (Foo) new ObjectMapper()
     .addMixIn(Foo.class, 
               IgnoreUnknownPropertiesMixin.class)
     .readValue(fooJson, Foo.class);
```